# No more disk space, nothing eating my disk. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

I had 100% of disk use on

```
/dev/xvda1
```

Which is the system partition, so I decided to mount

```
/var/lib
```

On another partition

```
/dev/xvdf
```

since docker files under /var/lib were eating much space.

I have always 100% of the root partition used.

```
udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  336K  395M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       99G   99G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdf       296G  765M  280G   1% /var/lib
```

and

```
lsof | grep deleted
```

shows nothing

And this is the output of `du -sh`

```
52M /admin
9.6M    /bin
25M /boot
12K /dev
5.9M    /etc
11M /home
0   /initrd.img
61M /lib
4.0K    /lib64
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/3945/task/3945/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3945/task/3945/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3945/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3945/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0   /proc
15M /root
336K    /run
9.4M    /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0   /status
0   /sys
8.5M    /tmp
1016M   /usr
877M    /var
0   /vmlinuz
```

The inode usage:

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             504621    397   504224    1% /dev
tmpfs            505859    315   505544    1% /run
/dev/xvda1      6553600 684402  5869198   11% /
none             505859     10   505849    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             505859      1   505858    1% /run/lock
none             505859      1   505858    1% /run/shm
none             505859      1   505858    1% /run/user
/dev/xvdf      19660800    202 19660598    1% /var/lib
```

Do you see any solution ?

Comment: Did you move the files from `/var/lib` to `/dev/xvdf` before you mounted it in that place (or cleaned the `/dev/lib` directory)? If not then these files are 'hidden' behind `/dev/xvdf` when you mounted it to `/dev/lib`. This can explain the missing disk usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested you probably have the original files underneath `/var/lib`. If you don't (or can't) usefully boot the system into single user mode you can also access these with a "bind mount":

```
mkdir -p -m700 /mnt/dsk
mount --bind / /mnt/dsk
cd /mnt/dsk/var/lib
```

You are now in the "old" `/var/lib` that is hidden underneath the "new" `/var/lib` and you can either delete or move files out of here as necessary.

**IMPORTANT** the files underneath `/mnt/dsk` are the *same files* as underneath `/`. They are not copies. If you delete these files you are actually deleting files on your root filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

That's because 'migrating' your `/var/lib` to another partition does not automatically clean your original files.

The trick would be to boot from another system (maybe a livecd), from there mount your `/dev/xvda1` and delete the files in there.

**Please be careful, and make sure all the files are actually available in your new partition before trying this.**

Comment: Why do you need to boot into another system? Can't you just mount `/dev/xvdf` to `/mnt` and move the files? Like this: `umount /dev/xvdf; mount /dev/xvdf /mnt; mv /var/lib/whatever* /mnt; umount /mnt; mount /dev/xvdf /var/lib`

Comment: Maybe yes, as long as the system doesn't need anything from /var/lib in the meantime. I'm not too sure...

Comment: @Lucas typically, a running system will have files open in `/var/lib` so unmounting it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

What is the sum of / ( `du -sh /` )? The same as in `df` 99G?
I thing files from `/var/lib` are still on `/dev/xvda1` partition. They are "hidden" under mounted partition `/dev/xvdf`. You must boot live cd (e.g. sysrescure), then:

```
mkdir /test 
mount /dev/xvda1 /test
```

and try

```
du -sh /test/var/
```

You should see your "hidden" space. You have to remove this files.