# How to free disk if df show full but du show free?

Tags: disk-usage

I have an cvm, the disk of which is full in recent day. I use `df -h`, it says the disk is almost full:

```bash
> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        99G   87G  7.2G  93% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G   11M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G   18M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb1       394G  317G   58G  85% /data
```

But when I used `du -sh` to find which file should to delete to free the disk, I got the different result, which said less than 50% space had been used:

```bash
> du -sh / --exclude=/data --exclude=/proc
38G /
```

I also checked there were no deleted files:

```
> lsof | grep delete
[no output]
```

There were also no hidden dir in root `/` dir:

```bash
> ls .[^.]*
.autorelabel
```

And I also checked there were no swap space:

```bash
> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       708Mi        21Gi        30Mi       8.5Gi        30Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

As directed by @telcoM, I checked the file system is EXT4:

```
> lsblk -o +fstype
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT FSTYPE
sr0     11:0    1 18.8M  0 rom             iso9660
vda    252:0    0  100G  0 disk
└─vda1 252:1    0  100G  0 part /          ext4
vdb    252:16   0  400G  0 disk
└─vdb1 252:17   0  400G  0 part /data      ext4
```

As directed by @xhienne, I called the `dumpe2fs`:

```
> dumpe2fs -h /dev/vda1 | grep ^Reserv
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Reserved block count:     1100904
Reserved GDT blocks:      1017
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
```

What more actions should I do to free the disk?

Comment: Please run `lsblk -o +fstype` to identify the filesystem type on `/dev/vda1`. Some filesystems have special requirements - for example, `btrfs` might be in need of a `btrfs balance`operation. Also, if you ran `lsof` as a regular user, it will only show information about files and processes owned by you. Run it as root (e.g. `sudo lsof +L1`) to show deleted files system-wide.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks. I checked the filesystem of vda1. It's ext4. I did call `lsof` as root rather other regular user.

Comment: Have you tried to check filesystem errors with fsck? Could it be the apparent size -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173947/du-s-apparent-size-vs-du-s

Comment: @pdem I tried `fsck -nf /dev/vda1` and there are many different errors: 10 Deleted inode N has zero dtime
7-Free blocks count wrong for group;
1-Free blocks count wrong;
17-Directories count wrong for group;
1-Free inodes count wrong. And the apparent size is 130T. Does this means I should fix the errors first?

Comment: @Jason You are not `fsck`-ing a FS that is mounted, are you? This would lead to a corruption for sure. Assuming `vda1` is a virtual disk for a VM: you must stop the VM in order to check the disk from outside (the VM host). If the FS still has errors, then correct them and recheck. Finally, start your VM and redo your `du`/`df` tests. BTW, do `du -x` instead of excluding mount points (you are probably missing /sys, /dev and others)

Comment: Who is doing `du` and `df`? Root or a non-privileged user? Run them as `root`. Moreover, can you add the result of `dumpe2fs -h /dev/vda1 | grep ^Reserv` to your question?

Comment: @xhienne Thanks. The exact command I called is `fsck -nf /dev/vda1 > fsck.log`. I got the vm from cloud, so I can only reboot it but I can't login the VM host. I can do little only inside the vm. I do these command as root inside the VM.

Comment: It's entirely possible you have stuff in the `/data` folder that's masked by the volume mounted on it

Comment: Thanks@muru. Although the problem is solve by the cloud vendor calling `fsck` on VM host, we still desire to hear more detail about how the `/data` may influent the `df` or `du` result if it's mounted from another device. Could you explain more?

Comment: Hi. @xhienne I contacted the cloud vendor, and they called `fsck` on VM HOST to repair the filesystem error. After the simple action, my VM df came normal and when I called `fsck` inside my VM, there were much less error than before. I believe your comment is helpful to check a filesystem error. Could you make a summary as formal answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Jason Glad thinks work better now. My comment is not worth being accepted as an answer. Actually, considering the cause of your issue, I'm not sure this question should stay here, even if it indeed may be helpful to others. You may want to write your own answer and accept it later, though. PS: you must NOT run `fsck` on a mounted ext4 filesystem (i.e. inside your VM since `vda1` is mounted on `/`); if you have no other option, at least sync and remount `/` read-only before.

Comment: @xhienne My comment may be misleading. I should say "I call `fsck -nf` on the mounted device rather than repairing opitions". Do you mean I should close the question because the problem is too specific but not so general?

Comment: @Jason It's hard to say precisely if this question is legit. On the one hand, it may be seen as off-topic (« Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own -or went away when a typo was fixed- are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers. »), OTOH nothing prevent such a problem from happening to others. I have suggested that this question be closed for this reason; the community will decide what to do.

Comment: Regarding: _"we still desire to hear more detail about how the `/data` may influent the `df` or `du` result if it's mounted from another device"_: It is possible that the original `/data` (before the mount) takes a lot of space. Since there's another device mounted on this folder, `du` would not be able to find those files, since it would only see the files from the mounted device. If that was the case, unmounting `/data` and running `du` could have shown if that folder was indeed responsible for the space that was previously "missing".

Comment: @JasonPan here's an example of that happening: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284101/70524